# Trying to create array of strings to use in a destructuring function for removing object properties, only single string value works

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects as part of a data response that I am grouping together using lodash's `groupBy` via each object's groupName key.

Some of the items that come back have a `groupName` value of null, undefined or an empty string and lodash creates separate groups for each of those values.

I combine all of the falsey groups into a single group name "Uncategorized" and attempt to remove the original falsey groups to only return "Uncategorized" and all other truthy groups.

The problem I'm running into is that I'm trying to use the rest operator to remove the original falsy objects with undefined, null, and empty string keys by assigning them to a variable like `let groupKeysToRemove = ['undefined', 'null', '']` and then trying to remove them like `let { [groupKeysToRemove]: removed, ...groups } = initialGroups;` but it returns the same Object with nothing removed. I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or what but I am stumped.

Code via [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-robinson-sckj7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

```
const resources = [
  {
    groupName: undefined,
    name: "color organizer"
  },
  {
    groupName: null,
    name: "Bart_Simpson_200px"
  },
  {
    groupName: "Spread Sheets",
    name: "Backflow"
  },
  {
    groupName: "Spread Sheets",
    name: "220px-Marge_Simpson"
  },
  {
    groupName: "",
    name: "212px-Homer_Simpson_2006"
  },
  {
    groupName: "Spread Sheets",
    name: "Product 6"
  },
  {
    groupName: "Warranties",
    name: "Warranty Bart Simpson"
  },
  {
    groupName: "Warranties",
    name: "Warranty Product 2"
  },
  {
    groupName: "Warranties",
    name: "Warranty Product 3"
  }
];

let initialGroups = groupBy(resources, "groupName");

let uncategorizedGroups = [];

uncategorizedGroups.push(...initialGroups[undefined], ...initialGroups[null], ...initialGroups[""]);

const renameGroups = uncategorizedGroups.map((object) => {
  object.groupName = "Uncategorized";
  return object;
});

const renamedGroups = groupBy(renameGroups, "groupName");

console.log('RENAMED GROUPS: ', renamedGroups)

const groupKeysToRemove = "undefined"

let { [groupKeysToRemove]: removed, ...groups } = initialGroups;

groups = { ...groups, ...renamedGroups };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the brackets syntax  `[]` for the destructing operation as an index to a property of an object, not an array that you pass in.  It's analogous to calling for example `obj["a"]` vs `obj.a` to access the `a` field on `obj`.

So knowing this, you need to pass in 3 arguments to extract the values that you want to remove.  For null and undefined I had to put them in separate variables, it wasn't working when putting them directly in the brackets:

```
const nullKey = null;
const undefinedKey = undefined;

let { 
  [nullKey]: nullGroup,
  [undefinedKey]: undefinedGroup,
  [""]: emptyStringGroup, 
  ...groups } = initialGroups;

groups = { ...groups, ...renamedGroups };

console.log("initialGroups: ", initialGroups);
console.log("GROUPS: ", groups);
console.log("null group", nullGroup)
console.log("undef group", undefinedGroup)
console.log("emptyStringGroup group", emptyStringGroup)
```